# Помогите проверить расстановку запятых в предложениях с обособленными и однородными определениями?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Правило 1. Не выделяются запятыми определения, одиночные или распространённые, если они стоят перед определяемым существительным.

Правило 2. Определения являются НЕОДНОРОДНЫМИ, если они: характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, в разных отношениях, то есть выражают признаки, относящиеся к разным родовым (общим) понятиям.

Тогда получаются примеры (с причастным оборотом и однородными определениями):

1) Выкрашенный в зеленый цвет забор простоял несколько лет как новый.           (запятые не нужны ?)

2) Подъехав к дому, я увидел возле него выкрашенный в зеленый цвет деревянный забор.   (запятая только после "подъехав к дому" ?)

3) Подъехав к дому, я увидел стоящий возле него новый зеленый деревянный забор.   (запятые правильно ?)

4) Подъехав к дому, я увидел стоящий возле него новый выкрашенный в зеленый цвет деревянный забор. (здесь как быть с запятыми?)

5) Подъехав к дому, я увидел стоящий возле него, выкрашенный в зеленый цвет забор. (запятые правильно ?)

Answer (score 2):

4) За одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным оборотом - нужна запятая ([Розенталь, Однородные и неоднородные определения 1.6](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm#%D0%B7_02))

> Подъехав к дому, я увидел стоящий возле него новый, выкрашенный в зеленый цвет деревянный забор.

5) Неоднородные определения "стоящий возле него" и "выкрашенный в зеленый
цвет" характеризуют "забор" с разных сторон. Запятая не нужна.

> Подъехав к дому, я увидел стоящий возле него выкрашенный в зеленый
>   цвет забор.

С остальными согласна.

Answer (score 1):

1) Запятые не нужны. Причастный оборот стоит перед определяемым существительным.

2) Запятая поставлена верна.

3)Правильно.Новый зеленый деревянный забор - неоднородные определения.

4)Причастный оборот стоит после одиночного определения-прилагательного,запятая нужна. Подъехав к дому, я увидел стоящий возле него новый, выкрашенный в зеленый цвет деревянный забор.

5)Запятые поставлены верно.

О пунктуации при обособленных-необособленных определениях, см. здесь: [ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ ЧЛЕНАХ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=117#pp117)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется верным вариант, предложенный Сержем, то есть исправлен вариант 4, но в варианте 5 запятые поставлены. Однако при этом требуется пояснение того, ПОЧЕМУ обороты  являются однородными.

Дело в том, что в данной теме однородность одиночных определений и оборотов чисто условная, она не связана с их семантикой, но связана со структурой предложения. Поэтому создается впечатление, что два следующих подряд оборота **нельзя писать без запятой**, так как в противном случае будет неясен состав каждого оборота.